# How can I get the content of the subfield with batch script?

Tags: xml, batch-file, extract

I have the following xml:

```
<datafield tag="007G">
    <subfield code="c">GBV</subfield>
    <subfield code="0">688845614</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

and I try to extract the content of the `<subfield code="0"`  688845614

This is my code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims=>/<" %%i in ('findstr "007G" curlread.txt') do echo %%i
pause
```

but as output I only get `<datafield tag="007G">`

There could be many `<datafield tag="007G">` in the xml doc and I need to  get `<subfield code="0"` from every of it.

Comment: If you are interested in `<subfield code="0">`, why are you searching for `007G` then? Anyway, I recommend not to use a batch file for this as it does not understand XML files natively; rather use a language that can handle XML files as such...

Comment: Batch can't parse XML, and `findstr` only returns the lines that match what you searched for.

Comment: Vbscript, Jscript and Powershell all have capability to read XML files nativiely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to parse structured markup language as hierarchical data, rather than as flat text to scrape.

To return the data from only the first `<subfield code="0">` node, replace your `findstr` command as follows:

```perl
powershell "([xml](gc curlread.txt)).selectSingleNode('//subfield[@code=0]/text()').data"
```

If you will have multiple `<subfield code="0">` nodes and you want the data from all of them, then

```perl
powershell "([xml](gc curlread.txt)).selectNodes('//subfield[@code=0]/text()') | %%{ $_.data }"
```

XPath for the win.  You can also specify only `<subfield code="0">` nodes that are children of `<datafield tag="007G">` by modifying the XPath selector like this:

```perl
//datafield[@tag=\"007G\"]/subfield[@code=0]/text()
```

**Important:** Quotation marks in the XPath must be backslash escaped.

---

**Edit:** Given the XML you pasted in your comment below:

```XML
<datafield tag="007G">
    <subfield code="c">GBV</subfield>
    <subfield code="0">688845614</subfield>
</datafield>
<datafield tag="008G">
    <subfield code="c">GBV</subfield>
    <subfield code="0">68614</subfield>
</datafield>
```

... be advised that that is not fully valid XML.  Valid XML has a single hierarchical root.  Before your data can be parsed, you'll have to enclose it with a root tag.

Here's an example of how to do that:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set "xml=curlread.xml"
rem // Note that quotation marks in the XPath must be backslash escaped
set "xpath=//datafield[@tag=\"007G\"]/subfield[@code=0]/text()"

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell "([xml]('<r>{0}</r>' -f (gc %xml%))).selectNodes('%xpath%') | %%{$_.data}"'
) do (
    set "subfield=%%I"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo something useful with !subfield!
    endlocal
)
pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I  always get only "+" symbol as output. Don't understand what goes wrong

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko probably a PowerShell error message.  Maybe your XML file isn't fully valid?  Or possibly your XPath selector didn't match any nodes, so PowerShell choked when trying to access the `.data` property where none exists?  Try just running the `powershell "([xml](gc curlread.txt)).selectSingleNode('//subfield[@code=0]/text()').data"` command straight from the console and see whether you can read the full error message.

Comment: I've run the powershell bit only and the problem was indeed a powershell error message, namely the path to the xml file was wrong. The next problem is that now i do not get any output, not even an error message.

Comment: `PS C:\Users\NekhayenkoO\Desktop\CDSSkript> ([xml](gc curlread.xml)).selectSingleNode('//datafieldasdfasdf[@tag="007G"]/subfield[@code=0]/text()').data`
this does not produce any output despite having an xpath that is clearly nonsence. Do you have any idea on how to make the call more verbose?

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko If the result of that PowerShell snippet is an empty string, then the `for /f` loop will not be able to define `%subfield%`.  So on the line after `set "subfield=%%I"` just do `if not defined subfield echo No results found` or whatever you feel is appropriate.  Or you could rewrite the script as a [Batch + PowerShell hybrid script](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=45095#p45095), foregoing the PowerShell one-liner for as much additional logic as you would like.  Or you could just write the whole thing in PowerShell.  Or JScript or VBScript.

Comment: But how could it be the empty string if I certainly see the result in my xml. Maybe there are some syntax errors?

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko Difficult to say.  But for your sample XML in your question, my script pulls the `688845614` value successfully in my tests.

Comment: I tested it and it pulls the right value if only one datafield tag exists in xml. For 2 or more datafield tags the output is only "+"              `<datafield tag="007G">
    <subfield code="c">GBV</subfield>
    <subfield code="0">688845614</subfield>
  </datafield>
   <datafield tag="008G">
    <subfield code="c">GBV</subfield>
    <subfield code="0">68614</subfield>
  </datafield>`

Comment: it was just only a small snippet that I pasted here from the entire XML-File. I think my XML file is fully valid, because it has two root elements `<record xmlns="info:srw/schema/5/picaXML-v1.0"> </record>` and `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the top. I can't understand why doesn't it work when two or more datafields are in the XML-document?