# How to extract all the content between two tags in XML with batch findstr?

Tags: regex, xml, batch-file, findstr

I'm trying to extract everything between `<datafield tag="036E">` and `</datafield>`.

```
 <datafield tag="036E">
    <subfield code="a">Collana del dialogo ebraico-cristiano</subfield>
    <subfield code="l">1</subfield>
  </datafield>
```

Is it possible to do it with findstr and regex in batch such as `[036E">].*[</datafield>]`  ?

Comment: "Is it possible" is not quite a helpful question as the answer may simply be "yes" or "no". Anyway, `findstr` does not help as it searches text line-wise. However, I recommend a language that natively supports XML like JavaScript, VBScript or PowerShell, as `cmd`/batch-files do not understand the format and treat the data as usual text...

Comment: We told you the same thing about this type of processing in one of your previous questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106654/how-can-i-get-the-content-of-the-subfield-with-batch-script

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  But its not an easy-one-liner, if that is what you're looking for. First, you need to parse the file for line that has your initial tag.  Then you need to parse the file again for the first line with the closing tag that is after your initial tag.  Then you need to parse the file again, getting all the matching data.  As always ***Show Your Code***

Comment: (and that is only if there is just one matching field in your file.  If there are multiple fields, it will get a lot harder.   Batch is the wrong tool for this)

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (a tool I happen to maintain), you can write

```
open file.xml ;
ls //datafield[@tag='036E'] ;
```

Comment: Am I reading your documentation correctly.  They would have to install cygwin to use it?

Comment: Strawberry Perl should be enough ;-)

Comment: There are probably many similar tools with various dependencies. Just pick  the one that suits you; but use the right tool for the job.